# dynamically showing and hiding divs with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have the following code for my login system:

```
function handleLogin() {
    var e = $("#username").val();
    var p = $("#password").val();

    if(e != "" && p != "") {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'http://localhost/php/log.php', 
            crossDomain: true,
            data:  {username: e, password :p},
            dataType: 'json', 
            async: false,
            success: function (response) { 
                if (response.success) { 
                    alert("Your login worked");
                    $('#loginTest').html(e);
                } else {
                    alert("Your login failed");
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert('Could not connect to the database' + error);
            }
        }); 
    } else {
        alert("You must enter username and password");
    }
    return false;
}
```

When the login has worked, I get the correct alert, but then I want the login div to hide, and the div beneath it to show with the username (e) in it.

So basically I just need to work out how to hide the current div, then show another one.

The login div is called #loginPage and the div below it is called #loginTest

Comment: You use jquery Ajax and can't get a simple $('#loginPage').hide()  to work?

Comment: @Fuzzyma Indeed. I'm guessing the OP didn't write this code originally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hide()` and `show()`:

```
if (response.success) { 
    $('#loginPage').hide();
    $('#loginTest').show().html(e);
}
```

There are also `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, `slideUp`, `slideDown` to deal with the display/hiding of elements. You could even use `animate` to define your own transition. The [API](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) is always your friend in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

To show and hide any particular HTML element you can use **show()** and **hide()** functions of that element. Initially you can hide your loginTest div and only show loginPage div.

**Try this:**

```
function (response) { 
                if (response.success) { 
                    $(#loginPage).hide(); //Hiding login page div
                    $(#loginTest).show(); //Showing login test div
                    alert("Your login worked");
                    $('#loginTest').html(e);
                } else {
                    alert("Your login failed");
                }
```

You can also add time for showing and hiding your DIV. Like `$(#loginPage).hide("fast");` and `$(#loginTest).show("slow");`. It totally depends upon you what is your need.